# Skipping incorrect values with onErrorResume

Tags: spring-webflux, reactive-programming, rx-java2, reactive

I have RxJava problem with *onErrorContinue()* which officialy not exist.

```
Observable.fromIterable(List.of(1,2,3,4,5))
.flatMap(int -> {
if ( p % 2 == ) { return Observable.error(new RuntimeException("Cannot do this"));}
else { return p } 
.onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
.toList()
.subscribe();
```

Which return me undesired [1]. How I can deal with it to obtain [1,3,5]?
Inb4 cannot return any other things, like null or wrappers in flatMap.

Comment: Why not filter out values before `flatMap`, i.e., `filter(p -> p % 2 == 0).flatMap(...)`?

Comment: It was copy of my production code, ints represent some domain objects which is not important here.

Comment: What you try to do makes no sense in reactive, nor in plain java as a matter of fact. If you have a value you don't want to process, filter it out (or return Observable.empty()) so it will be skipped over.